# How to get all error messages in script tag by using Vee validate V4 in vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vee-validate, laravel-mix-vue3

I Am using Vue 3 with vee-validate V4, and I am unable to get all error messages inside the script tag. Is there any way to get all error messages inside the script tag?

```
<Form v-slot="{ errors }">
  <Field name="name" />
  <pre>
    {{ errors.name }}
  </pre>
</Form>
```

How do get all errors in the script tag?

Comment: try using `for loop`

Comment: the errors is a list, using a **for loop** like @norbekoff suggested you can iterate each of them

Comment: Yes! @AlexandreHeinen. But, that is right but I want to access it on Vue Js method.

Comment: I think what you need is **const form = ref()** then access **form.errors** (I'm not sure about the variable name). This is what I use on composition API with script setup.

Comment: With this **form** variable you have access to other methods and properties, for example **form.validate()**

Answer (score 0):

The Form `errors` only has one error per field, no way around that. Each field has it's own `errors` which is an array (and you can access that inside the Field via `v-slot={ errors }`).

You may want to call `this.$refs.form.validateField()` on each field and the result for that gives you an errors array which you could save into your data to show in the template:

```
<template>
    <Form ref="form">
      <Field name="name" @change="getAllErrors"/>
      <pre>
        {{ errors.name }}
      </pre>
    </Form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
     return {
       allErrors: []
     }
  },
  methods: {
    getAllErrors() {
      this.$refs.form.validateField('name').then((valid, errors) => {
         if (valid) {
            this.allErrors = [];
         } else {
            this.allErrors = errors;
         }
      });
    }
  }
}
</script>
```